# Why Java Lambda Type Inference deals only with method with unique parameter ?

Tags: lambda, java-8, inference, functional-interface

If the compiler can figure out the type of the method with only one parameter, why it is not able to do the same for methods with two parameters or more tacking acount the order of parameters ?

Here an example :

[image]

In another way, Why the compile can't figure out that str is a String (**First parameter** in the unique method, and also str2 is a String (**second parameter** in the unique method) ?

Comment: `(str, str2) -> str.length()`?

Comment: It can, `Processor stringProcessor = (str1, str2) -> str1.length();` is inferred correctly with `str1` and `str2` as `String`s.

Comment: @Eugene it works :) thanks

Comment: Round brackets can be omitted only in case when lambda expression has one parameter. JLS is pretty clear in this regard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems you are not defining this correctly:

```
(str, str2) -> str.length()
```

You should also receive a compile time error for the second example.